# Should I get all data once from db and filter the result using javascript functions or should I use mongoose find({..}) to filter data?

Tags: api, express, mongoose, url, query-string

I have a collection called videos, an array of video objects, one of them looks like this,

```
  {
        "votes": {
            "upVotes": 0,
            "downVotes": 0
        },
        "_id": "60331f421f1d093ab5424480",
        "videoLink": "youtube.com/embed/kd2KEHvK-q8",
        "title": "The Vanishing of Flight 370",
        "genre": "Movies",
        "contentRating": "12+",
        "releaseDate": "2019-04-13T18:30:00.000Z",
        "previewImage": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kd2KEHvK-q8/mqdefault.jpg",
        "viewCount": 20
   }
```

I want to implement multiple filtering like,
[this is how the filters are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjssF.png)

```
/v1/videos?title=top&genres=Education,Sports&contentRating=12%2B
```

If I want to filter according to *contentRating* as well as *genre* which can be an more than one (Education, Sports, etc..).
I want to know the best practice or the right way to do it.

Should I get all the data in a variable for ex **result** and then check what all query params are passed in the URL and then filter my **result** accordingly or should I do something like this :

```
Video.find({contentRating:"12+", genre:"Education","Sports"})
```

If I do something like I just mentioned above, I will have to make sure, both genre and contentRating are present in query param. If only one is present I will have to check with if(genre){...} or if(contentRating){...}. This results in a lot of if-else. How should I do it?